# Web sites freeze after clicking link - unexplainable ACK packet

Tags: debian, tcp, apache-2.4, internet-explorer, anti-virus

We have a **sporadic** problem accessing some internal links on websites. (Windows Firefox, Internet Explorer, Chrome)

**Behaviour**
On first clicking a link, the browser will load infinitely. The second click on the same link then works perfectly fine.

**The clients**
We are running Windows 7 on the client-side and already tried different browsers (IE11, Firefox and Chrome). Avira Antivirus has its Browser-Security plugin enabled on these clients.

**The web server**
The server is running Debian Jessie, Apache 2.4.10 and Joomla.

**Analyzing the network trace**
When we trace the connection using wireshark, we find that the webserver misses to react on an ackowledgement the client sends, then sends a FIN-package, which is ignored by the client. The client continues to use the same TCP-connection, that was finished by the server.

```
Network-Trace: (all captured within a single tcp session)
1. Client sends ACK
2. Server recieves ACK
3. Server sends FIN-package after 5 seconds
4. Client recieves FIN-package
5. Client ignores FIN-package and continues to send data
6. Server recieves data, sends ACK-package, but no answer on the data
7. The browser session freezes
```

**The avira plugin**
What we know so far is that the error wont occur, if we disable the Browser-Security plugin of Avira or exclude the URL from being monitored. Avira has confirmed the error, but cant tell us when it will be fixed.

**Questions**
Anyway, the problem occours only on **that** web server, all other web servers are not affected.

So it can be influenced by the configuration on the web server.

I'd like to ask if anyone experienced similar errors so far?

Another question would be if there are settings regarding Apache or the TCP-stack to disable the ACK (point 6) which seems to be incorrect anyway.

**EDIT**
The typo3 sites are also affected.

As a workaround: After increasing the keepalive on apache from 5s to 90s the error doesn't occour anymore. (But we'd like to avoid such high keepalives)

Comment: You are making some incorrect assumptions about the meaning of FIN. Sending a FIN means you have no more data to send after this packet. But you will keep receiving data. Only once each end has send a FIN and each end has send an ACK in response to the FIN from the other end is the connection completely done. That is the only way to cleanly close an open connection. An unclean shutdown of a connection could happen with a RST packet or due to a timeout. For example if a party is not going to receive all data send by the other end of the connection, it will respond with a RST.

Comment: @kasperd : Thanks. Sounds reasonable. The server sends the FIN, due to the avira bug the client ignores it and continues sending requests. The servers FIN isn't ACKed by the client. Any idea why the server isn't answering the new requests or sending a RST?